# Check condition with w\ jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
       <span class="red"></span> 
       <span class="hot"></span> 
</div>
```

On click I need to check if one of the elements has a particular class and if yes change it to another class. I think I'm having difficulty with targeting correct element.

```
$(".container").click(function() {
if ($(this).next().hasClass('red')) {
    $(this).find("red").removeClass("red").addClass("blue");
            $(this).find("hot").removeClass("hot").addClass("cold");
            // and a line of back-end code if condition is true
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this).find(".red").removeClass("red").addClass("blue");
$(this).find(".hot").removeClass("hot").addClass("cold");
```

You need to add a dot to the find param because it is a class.

EDIT

```
if ($(this).next().hasClass('red')) {
```

will never happen in your example. because the element with the red class is the first item in the container.**

EDIT2

```
$(".container").click(function() {
    $('span', this).each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('red')) {
            $(this).removeClass('red');
            $(this).addClass('blue');
        }

        if ($(this).hasClass('hot')) {
            $(this).removeClass('hot');
            $(this).addClass('cold');
        }
    });
});
```

Not sure if I understand you. But what this does is:

loop through all spans in the container.
check if the span has a specific class.
if so change class.

Let me know if I understood you right.

EDIT 3

```
$(".container").click(function() {
    $('span.red', this).removeClass('red').addClass('blue');
    $('span.hot', this).removeClass('hot').addClass('cold');
});
```

or if you only want to check the first span for a red class and the second span for the hot class use this:

```
$(".container").click(function() {
    var span = $('span', this);
        if ($('span', this).eq(0).hasClass('red')) {
            // do stuff if first span has class red
        }

        if ($('span', this).eq(1).hasClass('hot')) {
            // do stuff if second span has class hot
        }
    });
});
```

Last edit: :)

```
$(".container").click(function() {
    if ($('span:first', this).hasClass('red')) {
        $('.red', this).removeClass('red').addClass('blue');
        $('.hot', this).removeClass('hot').addClass('cold');        
        // and a line of back-end code if condition is true
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TaCsV/

Comment: Therefore my question -- how do I check for that?

Comment: @santa: This should work for that purpose. It will only target .red/.hot anyway.

Comment: I understand, but I need to have that check because I do other things from that code besides toggling class. I have a back-end code embedded if the condition is true.

Comment: I suppose this works but why do I need to loop through all spans in the container if I know to look in the first one?

Answer (score 0):

`.next()` fill find the [next *sibling*](http://api.jquery.com/next/) of the current node, not a child of the node.

Something like this might work better for you.

```
$('.container').click(function(){
  $('.red', this).addClass( 'blue' ).removeClass( 'red' );
  $('.hot', this).addClass( 'cold' ).removeClass( 'hot' );
});
```

Comment: True, but if I still need to check for a specific class how would I do that? if ($(this).children().hasClass('red')) {